# Are the molecules of lattice in quantum entanglement when they vibrate as a phonon?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-entanglement, crystals, phonons

As all the molecules in the lattice are vibrating together to form a wave and the [phonon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon) is a quantum phenomenon, it makes sense to me that all the molecules inside the lattice are in the entangled state which is changing with time like propagating wave.

But it's hard to believe that so [many molecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#Lattice_dynamics) (which are in the scale of $10^{23}$) are entangled at the same time.

Are the molecules in the quantum entangled state when phonon is present in the lattice?

---

P.S. I'd like to add a new argument supporting the entangled molecules' view because the comments and answers claim that phonon can be explained with binding force without introducing the entanglement.

Experimenters devised a [method](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/06/180605112110.htm) to detect the phonon using the Raman effect.
The Raman effect is inelastic scattering. The excitation of the phonon state emits a photon and the lattice goes to the lower state during the Raman effect. The process is a quantum phenomenon. When the phonon state emits a photon, the effect has to spread through the whole lattice immediately as the phonon is collective excitation.
And I don't think the instant collapse of the wavefunction of phonon by the emission of the photon is possible only with binding force. Some sort of non-locality has to be involved and so the quantum entanglement among molecules might be the reason because entanglement is non-local.

Comment: Well, they are bound in a crystal structure. That does not make them ‘entangled’ however.

Comment: @JonCuster As the phonon is quantum phenomenon, I think something has to be quantum. If the bounding makes phonon, it gets weird because we will be able to construct phonon with macroscopic lattice size.

Comment: Not everything 'quantum' is 'entangled'.

Comment: @JonCuster But all the molecules have to be connected in some way to form the collective excitement. So I thought of entanglement.

Comment: All you need is for them to be bound together by the interatomic potential. One would not consider the electron and proton in a hydrogen atom 'entangled'. No need.

Answer (score 2):

Particles participating in a wave motion are not usually entangled, and in the case of phonons in ordinary circumstances they are not.

The type of correlated motion that makes a wave is classical correlation. It is not different in principle from a mexican wave in a crowd. Each individual member of the crowd has their own individual state of motion, and this motion is correlated from one person to the next, but this is not quantum entanglement. The same goes for water molecules making a wave on the sea, and for atomic vibrations making a wave in a solid.

Quantum entanglement is happening when it is not possible, even in principle, to assign a state (e.g. a state of motion, or a spin state, or both) to each part of the system in and of itself. In technical language, the total state cannot be factorized into a product of states of subsystems. But we can easily make a wave using a product state. You just assign to each atom a state of oscillatory motion with the phase slightly advanced compared to the previous atom.

Comment: But the phonons are considered as sort of a particle. Let's say someone detect the phonon. Isn't the phonon detected in an instance at one point which makes the instant collapse of the phonon wave function. And it's hard to think that this collapse happens in instant only with bounding force.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I would answer "no", at least not in the usual sense of quantum entanglement. A phonon is certainly a collective motion of many particles in a solid, but there are similar collective motions that are not considered entangled (e.g. plasma oscillations).

Phonons can be well described semi-classicaly: the phonon modes are vibrational modes of the solid (which can be described classically), but the energy in the modes follows a Bose-Einstein distribution (which is a result of quantum mechanics). In some sense, I think that's the definition of not entangled: something isn't entangled if it can be well described classically or semi-classically. (You might be able to make this argument more rigorous by talking about the properties of the system's density matrix.)

I realize that's kind of handwavy, but you're kind of asking a philosophical question. As far as we know, quantum mechanics applies to everything with one giant multi-particle state for the universe --- including the atoms in any solid. Arguably, everything is entangled to some degree. Nothing is truely classical. So, where do we draw the line and say that something is entangled? I'm not sure, but I think that most physicists would agree that phonons normally don't count as entangled because you can describe them fairly accurately without too much quantum mechanics.

Yes, you can move to situations where a phonon interacts with something that's definitively quantum, but such interactions are typically very brief; perhaps something that's arguably entanglement occurs --- but only for a very short period of time (short even by quantum-mechanical standards). This can often be treated as a perturbation on top of a semi-classical system.

EDIT: I should also note that you can describe phonons in quantum terms while keeping the atoms as distinguishable particles. (See J. M. Ziman's book "Electrons and Phonons" section 1.3.) The fact that we can get away with distinguishable particles also suggests a lack of entanglement between the particles.

Answer (score -1):

> all the molecules inside the lattice are in the entangled state

No. They are not. Many-particle entanglement is only property of Einstein-Bose condensate (BEC). For that you need to cool down gas of bosons of ultra-low density about  $1/{100~000} $ the density of normal air to ultra-low temperatures close to absolute zero of $0K$. Transition to BEC phase temperature of matter is defined as $$T_{\rm BEC}=\left(\frac{n}{\zeta(3/2)}\right)^{2/3}\frac{2\pi\hbar^2}{m k_{\rm B}}$$
Where $n$ is particle density, $\zeta$ is Riemann zeta function and $m$ is boson mass.
Also not every atom is suitable for BEC, just ones with even mass number such as ${} ^2 \text{ H} , {} ^4 \text{He} , {} ^{208}\text{Pb}$, etc. Given this, it's unlikely that solid body high-density lattice atoms in room temperature will form BEC.

Comment: Wait, what? Surely you don't mean to suggest that the only many-body systems that exhibit entanglement are Bose-Einstein condensates?

Comment: @d_b To my knowledge if most particles in a macro-scale system are entangled, then by definition it's a BEC. Only entanglement methods and bosons can differ in a process.

Comment: What about a fractional quantum Hall state, for example?

Comment: @d_b Yes quantum Hall states are predicted in rotating BEC systems. Bose condensate can form from [quasi particle systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensation_of_quasiparticles) such as phonons, exitons, magnons, polaritons and etc. So, yes its a BEC too by definition.

Comment: Rotating BECs provide one possible realization of FQH phases, but this doesn't mean that  FQH phases are themselves BECs, and there are other realizations, like in semiconductor heterostructures or in bilayer graphene. Certainly one wouldn't say FQH phases are Bose condensates "by definition." (I would be interested to see what definitions you think imply this.) To give another example of a many-body system that is not a Bose condensate but exhibits entanglement, what about a system of free-fermions? (See https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504151, https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1724)

Comment: @d_b Entangled fermions forms a [composite boson](http://scholar.google.lt/scholar_url?url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5985&hl=lt&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0eFv7ZXDrTJb0b5-ptwfnoRXG_qA&nossl=1&oi=scholarr) , so it's still a BEC. So seems that you are running from problem in principle.

Comment: Ok, I'm willing to accept this and interested in understanding it better. Can you point me to some references that discuss the general relationship between many-body entanglement and Bose condensation?

Comment: I would recommend paper [Many–particle entanglement with Bose–Einstein condensates](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0006111.pdf) and [Bell Correlations in a Bose-Einstein Condensate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06419.pdf). Later you can search for other papers by googling "many particle entanglement in BEC" in google scholar paper search engine. There's plenty of them there.